# sed - how to remove A-Z from second column

Tags: bash, sed

I've been able to do this in pieces via awk print $2, sed [a-z] etc, but how would I do this to one stream via sed all at once?

```
host_192.168.0.100 host_192.168.0.100
```

Turns into

```
host_192.168.0.100 192.168.0.100
```

Also, 'host' is just a placeholder, I really do need 'all' letters removed leaving numbers/punctuation.

Edit:: Grabbing the underscore would be nice as well, however I'm sure I can figure that out
Some other common examples would be:

```
ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0 ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0 
01-admin-10.10.10.10 01-admin-10.10.10.10
10.10.10.10-NAT 10.10.10.10-NAT
1test-10.10.10.10 1test-10.10.10.10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the second example, it appears that you want to remove all the non-digits appearing after the first white space, logically before the first digit.  You need it to remove dashes, underscores, even dots, as well as letters; anything that isn't a digit.  That suggests:

```
sed -e 's/ [^0-9]*/ /'
```

This is fairly minimalistic, but meets your criteria:

```
$ cat data
host_192.168.0.100 host_192.168.0.100
ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0 ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0 
$ sed -e 's/ [^0-9]*/ /' data
host_192.168.0.100 192.168.0.100
ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0 000.000.000.0 
$
```

A large part of the skill in writing good regular expressions is writing a good description of what you want the regular expression to actually do (in terms that make sense to regular expressions).

---

The three new items with leading digits and letters, and with trailing material, complicate life considerably:

```
$ cat data
host_192.168.0.100 host_192.168.0.100
ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0 ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0 
01-admin-10.10.10.10 01-admin-10.10.10.10
10.10.10.10-NAT 10.10.10.10-NAT
1test-10.10.10.10 1test-10.10.10.10
$ sed -e 's/ [^0-9]*/ /' \
>     -e 's/ [^.]*-\([0-9][0-9.]*[0-9]\)/ \1/' \
>     -e 's/ \([0-9][0-9.]*[0-9]\)[^0-9.].*$/ \1/' data
host_192.168.0.100 192.168.0.100
ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0 000.000.000.0
01-admin-10.10.10.10 10.10.10.10
10.10.10.10-NAT 10.10.10.10
1test-10.10.10.10 10.10.10.10
$
```

The `sed` script acquires 3 independent cleaning expressions.  The first, as before, removes any non-digits immediately after a space.  It is unlikely to need tweaking.

The `01-admin-` line though is untouched by that; the second regular expression deals with that by looking for a blank, a sequence of non-dots followed by a dash, and then capturing a sequence starting with a digit, continuing with interleaved digits and dots, and ending with a digit, replacing it with the remembered string of digits and dots. Matching the dash is key to that working sanely; if you're not careful, the `*` is too greedy (so, for example, `s/ .*\([0-9][0-9.]*[0-9]\)/\1/` gobbled the leading digits off the IP-address component).  I'm assuming that `sed` doesn't have non-greedy quantifiers such as `*?`; you might come up with a different answer if your version does (but this version will work as well). You may need to tweak that pattern to handle other exceptional cases; please do that for yourself, not as an edit to this question.

The third regular expression deals with the trailing `-NET` and other such material; it looks for and remembers the sequence of digits and dots (starting and ending with a digit), followed by a non-digit, non-dot character and any other trailing material, replacing it with the remembered string of digits and dots.  This is unlikely to need much tweaking.

Comment: This has the best result so far, however certain ones aren't picked up yet. I added a few more examples (leading numbers, training letters etc). Think you can handle it? :)

Comment: How were you able to limit the sed command to the second column? I'd be able to clean this up further if you could elaborate

Comment: Looks great, thank you Jonathan (especially for the explanation)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) [a-z_-]*\(.*\)/\1 \2/i'
```

**Edit:** Updated to reflect the changed requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic way that could work:

```
sed 's/ [A-Za-z_]*/ /'
```

Example:

```
$ sed 's/ [A-Za-z_]*/ /' <<<'host_192.168.0.100 host_192.168.0.100'
host_192.168.0.100 192.168.0.100
```

Comment: This seems to work better than the one posted by Ansgar, however if there are hyphenated characters the preceding ones aren't caught. Example would be:
ab-ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0

turns into -ab-abababab-ABABABAB-000.000.000.0

Comment: I need them *all* removed :)

Comment: Try replacing `[A-Za-z_]` with `[^0-9.]` that should remove everything up to the leading digit.

Comment: @Numpty You can either try William's advice or add the hyphen to the class I use: `s/ [A-Za-z_-]*/ /`